# Micronaut @Replaces with declarative Client

Tags: spock, micronaut

I am going to use the code from Micronaut Documentation (Declarative Http Client)- And I'm using Spock

PetOperations.java

```
@Validated
public interface PetOperations {
    @Post
    Single<Pet> save(@NotBlank String name, @Min(1L) int age);
}
```

I have a declarative client:

```
@Client("/pets") 
public interface PetClient extends PetOperations { 

    @Override
    Single<Pet> save(String name, int age); 
}
```

**My goal is** when I run a test class, I want to call (@Replaces) another class (**PetDummy**) instead of the ***PetClient***, PetDummy class is located in my test folder

```
@Primary
@Replaces(PetClient.class)
@Singleton
public class PetDummy implements PetOperations {

    @Override
    public Single<Pet> save(String name, int age) {
        Pet pet = new Pet();
        pet.setName(name);
        pet.setAge(age);
        // save to database or something
        return Single.just(pet);
    }
}
```

test class:

```
class PetTest extends Specification {

    @Shared
    @AutoCleanup
    ApplicationContext applicationContext = ApplicationContext.run();
    //EmbeddedServer server = applicationContext.getBean(EmbeddedServer.class).start();

    PetClient client = applicationContext.getBean(PetOperations.class);


    def 'test' (){
        given: 'name and age'

        when:
        client.save("Hoppie", 1);

        then:
        noExceptionThrown()
    }
}
```

However, **at the end PetClient is called**, I have as well tried with the @Factory annotation, but no success

PetClient *extends* PetOperations and PetDummy *implements* PetOperations, if they both implement then it will make sense to use @Replaces ...

Is there something else I can try out?

Thank you!

**Another Issue:**

Now that it works, the PetClient is a dependency in my PetService. When I test my PetService, it still calls the PetClient instead of the PetDummy.

I assume it has to do with the applicationContext, you will see

PetService:

```
PetService {
    @Inject
    PetClient client;

    buyFood(){
        //...
        Single<Pet> pet = client.save("Hoppie", 1));
    }
}
```

PerService Test:

```
class PetServiceTest extends ApplicationContextSpecification {

    @Subject
    @Shared
    PetService petService = applicationContext.getBean(PetService)

    PetOperations client = applicationContext.getBean(PetOperations.class) //client is not used here

    def 'test' (){
        given:

        when:
        petService.buyFood()

        then:
        noExceptionThrown()
    }
}
```

I think that I need to "get into" the applicationContext from the PetService, to tell "use the PetDummy" implementation (Inside the test class, because the ApplicationContextSpecification belong to another module

The ApplicationContextSpecification is:

```
abstract class ApplicationContextSpecification extends Specification implements ConfigurationFixture {

    @AutoCleanup
    @Shared
    ApplicationContext applicationContext = ApplicationContext.run(configuration)

/*    def cleanup() {
        assert !hasLeakage()
    }*/

}
```

The ConfigurationFixture contains the properties for the database(hibernate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already retrieving the `PetClient` bean implementation:

```
PetClient client = applicationContext.getBean(PetOperations.class);
```

Which should provide the replacing dummy bean implementation if called with the appropriate type:

```
PetOperations client = applicationContext.getBean(PetOperations.class);
```

Comment: I have another issue, i am preparing the example

Comment: I have included the issue under "Another Issue"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68743296/micronaut-replaces-with-declarative-client-continue I have created a new post @tmarwen