# Micronaut @Replaces with declarative Client (continue)

Tags: spock, micronaut

I have the following scenario:

A declarative Client

```
@Client("/pets") 
public interface PetClient extends PetOperations { 

    @Override
    Single<Pet> save(String name, int age); 
}
```

A PetDummy class, which @Replaces the PetClient during for testing

```
@Primary
@Replaces(PetClient.class)
@Singleton
public class PetDummy implements PetOperations {

    @Override
    public Single<Pet> save(String name, int age) {
        // do something
        return Single.just(pet);
    }
}
```

And a PetService class that has the declarative client as dependency

```
PetService {
    @Inject
    PetClient client;

    buyFood(){
        //...
        Single<Pet> pet = client.save("Hoppie", 1));
    }
}
```

When I test my PetService, my **goal** is that the test **calls the PetDummy class instead of the PetClient**

I assume it has to do with the applicationContext, you will see

PetService:

```
PetService {
    @Inject
    PetClient client;

    buyFood(){
        //...
        Single<Pet> pet = client.save("Hoppie", 1));
    }
}
```

PerService Test:

```
class PetServiceTest extends ApplicationContextSpecification {

    @Subject
    @Shared
    PetService petService = applicationContext.getBean(PetService)

    PetOperations client = applicationContext.getBean(PetOperations.class) //somehow i need to tell the application context to use the PetDummy class

    def 'test' (){
        given:

        when:
        petService.buyFood()

        then:
        noExceptionThrown()
    }
}
```

I think that I need to "get into" the applicationContext from the PetService. However, the ApplicationContextSpecification belongs to another module, so it won't recognise the PetDummy implementation

The ApplicationContextSpecification is:

```
abstract class ApplicationContextSpecification extends Specification implements ConfigurationFixture {

    @AutoCleanup
    @Shared
    ApplicationContext applicationContext = ApplicationContext.run(configuration)
  
}
```

The ConfigurationFixture contains the properties for the database(hibernate)

Comment: "Please refer to the post to get a better overview about the problem (Thank you!)" - FYI It might be better if you can make this question a self contained question.  That other question could be changed, or closed etc.

Comment: you are right, thank you! I have updated the question